# Beautifulsoup is pulling the rounded decimals (whats visible) from table and not actual cell values

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to pull data from webpage table. The data displayed on the page is a rounded 3 decimal places but the actual cell values are 4 decimal places. I need the full, un-rounded number.

My loop:

```
for i in range(0,20):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source,'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[i]
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    print(region,i)
    print( tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql') )
```

The webpage element:

```
 <span class="price-data " data-amount="{&quot;regional&quot;: 
 {&quot;asia-pacific-east&quot;:0.022,&quot;japan- 
 east&quot;:0.0176,&quot;japan-west&quot;:0.0206,&quot;us- 
 west&quot;:0.0164,&quot;us-west-2&quot;:0.0144,&quot;us-west- 
 central&quot;:0.018,&quot;west-india&quot;:0.0193}}" data-decimals="3" 
 data-decimals-force="3" data-month-format="{0}/month" data-hour-format=" 
 {0}/hour" data-region-unavailable="N/A" data-has-valid- 
 price="true">$0.018/hour</span>
```

My code displays the `0.018/hour` and I need it to display `0.0176/hour`.

Note: this is for japan-east (the sample data also has japan-west).

Comment: Reason is because you’re pulling the text/content as displayed in the html. You’ll have to look and see if you can pull the original source of that and parse that.

Comment: what is `region` ? it is not defined in your code. I do not see how your code prints anything resemlying 0.018/hour .. you `pd.read_html(str(table))` a table attribute but you do not show the table data - only a span ...

Comment: What is the URL for this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the JSON is correctly formatted, you could extract it from the `data-amount` attribute in the `<span>` as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
import json

html_text = """<span class="price-data " data-amount="{&quot;regional&quot;:{&quot;asia-pacific-east&quot;:0.022,&quot;japan-east&quot;:0.0176,&quot;japan-west&quot;:0.0206,&quot;us-west&quot;:0.0164,&quot;us-west-2&quot;:0.0144,&quot;us-west-central&quot;:0.018,&quot;west-india&quot;:0.0193}}" data-decimals="3" data-decimals-force="3" data-month-format="{0}/month" data-hour-format="{0}/hour"data-region-unavailable="N/A" data-has-valid-price="true">$0.018/hour</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
da = html.unescape(soup.span['data-amount'])
data_amount = json.loads(da)

print(data_amount['regional']['japan-east'])
```

Which would display:

```
0.0176
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also correct the json as shown and use the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
html = '''<span class="price-data " data-amount="{&quot;regional&quot;: 
     {&quot;asia-pacific-east&quot;:0.022,&quot;japan- 
     east&quot;:0.0176,&quot;japan-west&quot;:0.0206,&quot;us- 
     west&quot;:0.0164,&quot;us-west-2&quot;:0.0144,&quot;us-west- 
     central&quot;:0.018,&quot;west-india&quot;:0.0193}}" data-decimals="3" 
     data-decimals-force="3" data-month-format="{0}/month" data-hour-format=" 
     {0}/hour" data-region-unavailable="N/A" data-has-valid- 
     price="true">$0.018/hour</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
items = soup.select('span.price-data')
for item in items:
    if item.has_attr('data-amount'):
        val = json.loads(item['data-amount'].replace('\n', ' ').replace(' ',''))
        print(val['regional']['japan-east'])
```